# 301 Redirecting to azure storage blob is inadvertently passing App credentials

Tags: javascript, azure, asp.net-core, storage

Previously over the last few months I have been serving azure blobs via a 301 redirect from a azure Web API. Authorised clients can access the Web API via a bearer token.

1. Client visits myapp.azurewebsites.net/api/file/2
2. The webapp generates an SASS url for the file in blob storage
3. The webapp returns the SASS url as a 301 redirect
4. The client's browser follows this and downloads the file transparently.

However recently an error is now being raised from the Azure Blob Api after the redirect:

`InvalidAuthenticationInfo - Authentication information is not given in the correct format. Check the value of Authorization header.`

Which is suggesting my Bearer token for the Web API is being inadvertently passed onto blob storage, checking the network tab in chrome and it is indeed passing the credentials to azure blob storage.

Is there a way to make the storage API ignore the bearer token and just use the SASS key in the url?
Or is there a way to prevent a 301 redirect from leaking credentials to another domain?

ASP.Net Core:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetContent(string id)
{
     //var sassUri = https://myblob.blob.core.windows.net/TEST?sv=2020-04-08&se=2021-04-07T13%3A16%3A15Z&sr=b&sp=r&sig=4WBAkWx
     var sassURI = await _fileService.GetSASSForFileIdAsync(id);
     return new RedirectResult(sassURI, true);
}
```

Javascript:

```
const myHeaders = new Headers();

myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
myHeaders.append('Authorization', 'bearer 607cd0a9-6048'); //token for myapp

let resp = await fetch('https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/file/2',{ method: 'GET', headers: myHeaders});
//Network tab shows credentials are being leaked to myblob.blob.core.windows.net
console.log(resp);
```

Comment: I believe if you just pass the SAS and remove the Bearer token should work

Answer (score -1):

Of course, you could request storage API with SAS URL, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json).

[image]

Azure Storage supports three types of shared access signatures:

1. User delegation SAS
2. Service SAS
3. Account SAS

For example, create a **service** SAS for a blob container using [`GenerateSasUri`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient.generatesasuri?view=azure-dotnet) method:

```
private static Uri GetServiceSasUriForContainer(BlobContainerClient containerClient,
                                          string storedPolicyName = null)
{
    // Check whether this BlobContainerClient object has been authorized with Shared Key.
    if (containerClient.CanGenerateSasUri)
    {
        // Create a SAS token that's valid for one hour.
        BlobSasBuilder sasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder()
        {
            BlobContainerName = containerClient.Name,
            Resource = "c"
        };

        if (storedPolicyName == null)
        {
            sasBuilder.ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1);
            sasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobContainerSasPermissions.Read);
        }
        else
        {
            sasBuilder.Identifier = storedPolicyName;
        }

        Uri sasUri = containerClient.GenerateSasUri(sasBuilder);
        Console.WriteLine("SAS URI for blob container is: {0}", sasUri);
        Console.WriteLine();

        return sasUri;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(@"BlobContainerClient must be authorized with Shared Key 
                          credentials to create a service SAS.");
        return null;
    }
}
```